# GitHub API find all commits by user ID with timestamp

Tags: github, github-api

Is there an efficient way to find all recent commits by a specific user across all public repos?

I am currently use `/events/public` and filtering out those `event.type === "PushEvent"`. However this is not very efficient because

- The commits in the `PushEvent` does not have [timestamp](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent), which means I need additional requests to fetch their timestamps through `commits[][url]`.
- There is a limit of 60 requests/hour which gets quickly used up because I need to fetch timestamp of each commit.

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No unfortunately there is no better way to retrieve commits for the user.
However there is a workaround for the rate limit:

[Documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting) says

> For requests using Basic Authentication or OAuth, **you can make up to 5,000 requests per hour**. For unauthenticated requests, the rate limit allows you to make up to 60 requests per hour.

You can generate an [access token](https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens) and [use it as an OAuth token](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#via-oauth-tokens).

**How to use token**

If you're going to use [Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)
you need to add new header

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l
```

where the string after `Basic` is a [Base64 encoded](https://www.base64encode.org/) string of

```
your_user_name:your_token
```

**If you're using `curl`**

```
curl -u username:token https://api.github.com/user
```

or

```
curl https://username:token@api.github.com/
```

Comment: Any idea how I can use them in http API requests? The example only shows curl.

Comment: Yes, you need to provide Authorization header

Comment: I see on the wiki link there is a section on url encoding, is that a possible way as well?

Comment: I'm not sure if GitHub accepts that. You can give it a try

Comment: It works! `curl https://paradite:mypersonalaccesstokenstring@api.github.com/rate_limit` returns 5000!

Comment: Glad to help. Have fun!

Comment: maybe you can update your answer and i will accept it.

Comment: Updated. now we have two options for curl